# struts 2.0 iterator Tags prbm

Tags: java, struts2, struts

I have a jsp and a struts 2.0 action class. I am setting a List in my action class, that I will be using in my jsp.

the model classes are:

```
public class Student {
    int stdid;
    String stdName;
    String stdroll;
    Address stdAddress;
}

public class Address {
    String houseNo;
    String street;
    String area;
    String state;
    String country;
    String pin;

}

public class IteratorKFCAction extends ActionSupport{

    private List<Student> studentList;

    public List<Student> getStudentList() {
        return studentList;
    }

    public void setStudentList(List<Student> studentList) {
        this.studentList = studentList;
    }

    public String execute() {

        studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        studentList.add(std1);
        studentList.add(std4);
        studentList.add(std3);
        studentList.add(std2);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Now, on my jsp I want to display each student address.
I want to display, the addess of the student with a particular pin code. Can someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show what you have tried so far and what results you are getting. How are those results different from what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use struts tags to iterate a list in JSP.

Import struts tags library into JSP file.

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
```

Now iterate the list available in request scope.

```
<s:iterator value="#studentList" var="student">
   <label><s:property value="%{#student.stdAddress.houseNo}"/></label><br>
   <label><s:property value="%{#student.stdAddress.street}"/></label><br>
   <label><s:property value="%{#student.stdAddress.area}"/></label><br>
   <label><s:property value="%{#student.stdAddress.country}"/></label><br>
   <label><s:property value="%{#student.stdAddress.pin}"/></label><br>
</s:iterator>
```

Also make sure that you have matching getters/setters method for fields in Student And Address classes.